# Second order conditions in linear programming problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I know, that in linear programming problems, in order to find maxima or minima, you search for corner solutions of a polyhedron. So, there is a system of linear equations, that you are trying to solve with a specific process, namely the simplex method or KKT method. But why should someone search for second order conditions. Since linear programming is not a field that I have seen so much, I have in mind that second order conditions should be zero. Is there any chance that this is different than zero?

Comment: Even using the first order condition makes no sense.

Comment: i know....but a professor at the university asked to do so :P maybe he is desperate

Comment: Probably he has some problems with getting older :)

Comment: @callculus: I am not sure what you are talking about, but the first-order conditions are used all the time in linear programming.

Comment: @gerw I've never used FOC's in context of linear optimizing.

Comment: @callculus: This seems to be very strange to me. What have you done in linear programming? Even checking optimality of the final stage of the simplex algorithm is in principle a verification of the optimality conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, second order conditions seem to be satisfied in most of the cases. Let us take the simple example of optimizing
$$f(x) = \alpha x$$
over $x \in [0,1]$. Here, "most of the cases" means $\alpha \ne 0$ and w.l.o.g. we discuss $\alpha > 0$. Then, $\bar x = 0$ is the point of interest. In this point, the first-order condition is
$$
f'(\bar x) h \ge 0 \qquad \forall h \ge 0$$
and this is satisfied due to $f'(\bar x) = \alpha > 0$.
The second-order conditions involve the critical cone
$$
C := \{ h \ge 0 \mid f'(\bar x) h = 0 \}.
$$
The necessary condition is
$$
h^\top f''(\bar x) h \ge 0 \qquad \forall h \in C
$$
(with the Hessian "matrix" $f''(\bar x)$)
and the sufficient condition is
$$
h^\top f''(\bar x) h > 0 \qquad \forall h \in C \setminus \{0\}.
$$
Note that both conditions are (trivially) satisfied due to $C = \{0\}$.

(However, much more is true: Even the first-order sufficient condition
$$
f'(\bar x) h > 0 \qquad \forall h > 0
$$
is satisfied.)

Comment: Ok, but explain me something. What is the role of second order conditions in linear programming (namely in a constrained optimization problem where we have a system of linear inequalities)? The Hessian matrix needs to satisfy the criteria for (local) maximum/minimum points. In case of a quadratic, logarithmic, exponential or a combination of them function, it makes sense. Why someone should need second order conditions to solve a linear programming problem? You know ex-ante that the second order conditions are zero...If you know something more, please give me more details. Thank you!

Comment: In linear programming, the objective is linear, hence, its Hessian is zero. But still, the sufficient second-order condition can be satisfied (see above). In order to solve the problem, you, however, do not need the second-order conditions.

Comment: explain me where is this point that the second order can be satisfied? Can you clarify what you say a little more?

Comment: The second-order condition is satisfied because the critical cone $C$ reduces to $\{0\}$. At which point do you need further clarification?

Comment: oooh you mean that the critical cone $C=\{0\}$ because of the linearity of the function, right?

Comment: No, this is not due to the linearity, it is due to the fact that (often), the derivative of the objective does not vanish on the tangent cone.